# How to enable JVM debugging for yarn jobs on IBM Analytic Engine?

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

I have a [problem with a yarn application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529339/output-stream-closed-at-org-apache-hadoop-fs-s3a-s3aoutputstream-checkopen) running on IAE.  One option that I would like try to investigate the issue is enabling JVM remote debugging so that I can connect from my IDE and step through the problematic code.  Normally jvm options for debugging look something like this:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=y,suspend=y
```

Users don't have root access on IAE, so I'm would like to know how I can configure yarn to run with the JVM remote debug options set?

I believe I will also need to set up an SSH tunnel for the remote JVM debugging because IAE sits behind a firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with IBM Analytics Engine.

Please raise a support ticket describing your issue.

Comment: If it is an enhancement request, it is better to open a request here rather than open a ticket: https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/